# Sharepoint new file upload version saved as Minor rather than Major version

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have the below setting checked on Sharepoint sandbox account.

Create major and minor (draft) versions
 Example: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0

Whenever I am trying to upload a new file with some metadata properties the version is setting to 0.1 (Minor Version).
Is there any way i can get this first time upload to 1.0 (Major Version) in sharepoint.

```
var uploadFile = folder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

// Update item properties

var item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;

item.ValidateUpdateListItem(itemMetadata, true, "abc");

context.Load(uploadFile);

context.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry();
```

Also the checkin comments don't get displayed for the first time unless it is a major version.

Answer (score 0):

```
// your code
uploadFile.Publish("Comments for this version...");
uploadFile.Update();
context.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry();
```